# How can I delete all but one object in a Core Data store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, restkit

Is there an efficient way to delete all but one or a few objects in a Core Data store? Our current solution is to just delete the whole store (using `RKObjectStore.deletePersistantStore` -- we use RestKit) and reconstruct the object, but this isn't optimal since it involves an extra server request. Ideally, there would be some nice way to "detach" the object from the store, dump the store, and then re-insert it.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to save the object elsewhere, and then dump the store normally?

Comment: @ApopheniaOverload That's an option. It is kosher to just set the `objectStore` property on our `RKObjectManager` to point to the new object store? Or will this break things?

Comment: Just one object - that you dont want to delete - sounds like you could remove that from core-data and use that in `userDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

You could first get the number of objects and then fetch one less:

```
NSInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = count-1;
```

Execute the fetch, iterate through the results and delete them.

You could also reduce the database size by using the sqlite framework to send the store file a `vacuum` query, but this is not really necessary if it is going to fill up again anyway.